# Apache RPS With Lambda Function

Tags: aws-lambda

we had an issue that related with Apache RPS(Request Per Second)

We have lambda function that perform service take 40s and then send request to Apache API

but because its lambda function (serverless) it sends so many requests causing Dropping of requests.

any idea to solve this issue ?

Thank you